# Are there local commits in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Does TFS support local commits?

In other words: Can I

1. modify the code,
2. make a local commit (without sharing these changes with others),
3. test my modifications and
4. if my changes didn't break anything, do a global commit (thereafter my changes are available to other developers)

in TFS 2012?

If it doesn't, are there any workarounds, which allow this functionality?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No it doesn't support this, however it does have a couple of alternatives you can use instead.

1) Branches - All developers work on their own branch then merge to trunk/main when they're happy with their changes.

2) Shelveset - developers shelve any change they don't want to commit yet.  This lets you undo your change, or pass it to another developer on the team without losing the change or checking into the main branch

3) Gated Checkins + Unit/Automated tests.  Any time a developer checks in, TFS Automatically shelves the changes and runs the tfs build + any associated tests (unit or automated). If everything succeeds then it is checked in.  I don't believe this supports manual tests.

or a mix of all of the above.

Answer (score 10):

TFS does not support this by itself.

However! Microsoft released Git integration with TFS. Brian Harry blogged about this: [Announcing Git Integration with TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/08/13/announcing-git-integration-with-tfs.aspx) a couple of weeks ago.

Using this setup you can use Git for your local commits and then commit it to Team Foundation Server.

Comment: ha. +1 for "just use Git" :) if only that were an option in any shop I've worked in. I sometimes use local git within a TFS repo so that I can do branching, staging

Answer (score 1):

Not for the on premise version of TFS (yet), but as of January 2013 Microsoft's hosted Team Foundation Service has Git support, which obviously supports local commits.

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2013-jan-30.aspx#git%20support

Comment: I'm curious whether it will be possible to migrate a large codebase from TFS to Git without much pain (preserving history and links to work items) in TFS 2013.

Comment: Sadly I think it would be next to impossible. I tried playing with Git-TF but it couldn't understand TFS branching.  It only allowed you to pull and push from a single TFS branch.  You could make local Git branches, but not push them.  So sadly it's inability to migrate TFS branches would kill you, let alone stuff like work items. :(