# Is there a feature like TFS check in for local project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have TFS check in Visual Studio to save project progress until certain level. Similarly do we have any way to save progress until a particular point like checkpoints for local projects in Visual Studio. Th purpose is to save it when there is good progress and revert back to any of the saves that has been made

Edit 1: To be more clear I am not talking about the working with the local version of TFS code. I am meaning the **local projects that you create in the system** that is not connected to any server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636222/are-there-local-commits-in-tfs

Answer (score 0):

No, no such a feature in local Vistual Studio. Basically only one version of the sources will be keeping there in your local workspace.

So, as a workaround you can create a branch to manage the changes until certain level. Then merge to the Master/Dev branch as needed.

Alternatively you can use [Shelveset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets) or [Gated Checkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers#gated) as **Betty** mentioned in this thread : [Are there local commits in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636222/are-there-local-commits-in-tfs)

But as you can see that the ways are all need to sync to TFS. In my opinion **new branch** should be better if you want to manage the local changes before reaching the certain level.

Comment: Thanks Andy Li-MSFT. But I think I was not clear in my question. I am talking about the local projects that you create in the system that will not be connected to the server. Have updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Amalpriya So, it's not about TFS, right? Seems you mean local projects source control, based on my experience,no such a feature or product to achieve that. You'd better use source control Tools such as TFS here.